# Image upload widget that resizes an image and then uploads it

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I want to create an image upload widget that resizes (scales) images to a low res (say 640x640). I want to then upload these resized images to the server. Mainly to prevent huge file uploads.

What is the best way to implement it? I'm using JQuery and Django.

Answer (score 1):

Browser support for this will be limited although you can mitigate this by writing Flash and Silverlight shims that do the same thing. I've seen a few html5 examples of how to do this as well.

Plupload is a nice tool for managing this and gives you all the shims and uploaders detailed above.

http://www.plupload.com/example_all_runtimes.php

if you look at the example embed code there is a resize object as part of the config in which you can define the parameters described in your post

Comment: Pulpload seems perfect for my requirements! Thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Canvas and HTML5.

It's pretty simple, just use a FileReader (will not work on iOS/iPhone since they don't have files at a user level) to open on the File/File list you get back from an input type file element:

```
function fileSelectHandler(e) {
    files = e.target.files;
    var len = files.length;
    for(var filei = 0; filei < len; filei += 1) {
         var aFile = files[filei];
         var fileReader = new FileReader();
         fileReader.onload = (function (theFile) {
             return function(e) {
                 if(e.target.result != null && e.target.result != undefined) {    
                     var imge = new Image();
                     imge.src = e.target.result;
                     imageDataURLs[theFile.name] = imge;
                     imge.onload = (function () {
                         return function(e) {
                            draggables[0] = new Draggable(g3,imge);
                            draggableFlow.launch();
                         };
                     })();
                 }
             };
       })(aFile);
       fileReader.readAsDataURL(aFile);
   } // for next file 
};
```

Then write the image to a canvas element and enable the user to drag it around and crop it. When they're happy grab the data from the canvas using CanvasRenderingContext2D.getImageData, and send that base64 string to the server in XHR.

Comment: I'll give it a try. For iPhone/iPad, I'd like to write a separate app. So that's not much of an issue. Thanks for the detailed response :)